Data imputation for Laboratory Experiments
I have a timeseries dataset containing several experiments that were conducted in batches and concatenated (each batch is 48hours, with data recorded every 2 hours). However, there is a target variable (titer) which only has its value recorded at the end of the experiment (at time 48hours). How can i use machine learning to perform imputation. I know that titer is likely zero from the beginning of the experiment up to time 15 hours, and then starts to increase from there to time 48 hours.
Please can anyone help?

What exactly are you trying to impute?  If you didn't record the titer during the first 48 hours, what data do you have that might be related to titer and what information do you have about that relationship?  It sounds like you don't have anything.

There is basically no way to do what you are asking.
You have a precise estimate of titer at 48 hours, and you can use univariate statistics to describe this. You also have an assumption that titer is 0 at time 0. It turns out this is rarely a useful assumption, since assays are imprecise. But the main issue is that you have 0 samples at all at any time point between 0 and 48 hours.
Consider the huge number of functions and parameters that could predict titer at these intermediate times. The shape could be sigmoid, non-monotonic, it could be linear, or heaviside, or exponential.
At best, you could posit a linear or exponential model, but nobody would take this seriously as a "machine learning" or "AI" model for "imputation". Actually, the rationale for this kind of model is the opposite - it's based on your belief about the process.
If you could repeat your experiment, a statistician would have recommended to design experiments in blocks, and calculate titer at, say, 12, 24, 36, and 48 hours, or even more granular times as needed, and then to suggest a statistical estimation routine that is aligned with the physical model for the data to estimate the values.
